# How to open a specific chrome user using selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I can open the chrome user i wanted to open but the selenium wont go to the url i type. Below is my code and output after it open the chrome user.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\eugen\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 1")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe', chrome_options=options)

driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

**Ouput**:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0

Comment: I guess your user-data-dir location is wrong, its upto `C:\\Users\\eugen\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data` only. Also check the chrome browser version and chrome driver version, both should be in sync.